# Different routes calling to a function in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, php-8

I am migrating a site from core PHP to Laravel 8. I have to display the Business List page and the Business Details page in a module. I am working on Routes and get stuck with it. Those routes are -

```
Route::post("/business/{id1}/", [FrontendBusinessController::class,'show'])
    ->name('business_details');
Route::get("/business/{id}", [FrontendBusinessController::class,'business_list'])
    ->name('business_list');
```

Here, the trailing '/' is what differentiates the routes
'/business/{id} '  -  this route  is for business listing
'/business/{id}/ '  -  this route is for business detailed page

The difference between them is that the first route ends without a  '/' (slash), and the second route ends with '/'. The problem I face is both of the routes get directed to the 'show' function. I wonder how to fix this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

this / it doesn't work it takes to the same route

you can use this double slash //

```
Route::post("/business/{id1}//", [FrontendBusinessController::class,'show'])->name('business_details');
```